# How to count words between two words?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get number of words between specific words from database.
for example

```
-----------------------------------------------
|    ID    |  DESCRIPTION                     |
-----------------------------------------------
|     1    |  Back to the drawing board.      |
|     2    |  Actions speak louder than words |
|     3    |  Board is very large to carry    |
-----------------------------------------------
```

when I search on description field words "to" and "board" I need 
following output:

```
----------------------
|    ID    |  COUNT  |      
----------------------
|     1    |    2    |
|     2    |    0    |
|     3    |    3    |
----------------------
```

Is there any way to achieve such type of output with MySQL.

Comment: Do you know that words are separated by exactly one space?

Comment: It can be vary. But in most cases there will be only single space

Answer (score 0):

You can find the position of each word -- assuming only a single space between words -- by doing:

```
select (length(substring_index(concat(' ', description, ' '), ' to ', 1)) - 
        length(replace(substring_index(concat(' ', description, ' '), ' to ', 1), ' ', '')
       ) as to_pos
```

You can then combine this to get what you want as something like:

```
select (case when description like '%to%board%'
             then (length(substring_index(concat(' ', description, ' '), ' board ', 1)) - 
                   length(replace(substring_index(concat(' ', description, ' '), ' board ', 1), ' ', '')
                  ) -
                  (length(substring_index(concat(' ', description, ' '), 'to', 1)) - 
                   length(replace(substring_index(description, ' to ', 1), ' ', '')
                  )
              when description like '%board%to%'
             then (length(substring_index(concat(' ', description, ' '), ' to ', 1)) - 
                   length(replace(substring_index(concat(' ', description, ' '), ' to ', 1), ' ', '')
                  ) -
                  (length(substring_index(concat(' ', description, ' '), ' board ', 1)) - 
                   length(replace(substring_index(concat(' ', description, ' '), ' board ', 1), ' ', '')
                  )
         end)
```

This will actually work with multiple spaces, if there are no multiple spaces between the two words.  The multiple spaces can be before or after.